# Using variables in parallel list comprehensions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

In a [parallel list comprehension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#parallel-list-comprehensions) in Haskell, I encounter a problem when trying to use a guard.

```
largestPalindrome :: Int -> Int
largestPalindrome x = maximum [ a*b
                              | a <- [x,x-1..1]
                              | b <- [x,x-1..1]
                              , isPalindrome (a*b) ]
```

The error that is displayed is

```
Variable not in scope: a :: Int
```

Comment: If you make it in parallel, you would not be able to link `a` and `b`, am I right? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Note that, if you compute them in parallel, you always get `b=a`.

Answer (score 6):

Quoted from [Haskell Prime](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/ParallelListComp):

> Parallel comprehensions extend list comprehensions with a notation for
>   zips. The comprehension
>
> ```
> [ e | quals1 | ... | qualsN ]
> ```
>
> can be desugared to
>
> ```
> zipWithN (\ p1 ... pN -> e) [p1 | quals1] ... [pN | qualsN]
> ```
>
> where `pi`
>   is a tuple of the variables defined by `qualsi` and used by `e`.

So, from your example, `[a*b |a<- [x,x-1..1] | b <- [x,x-1..1] , isPalindrome (a*b)]` is roughly equivalent to

```
zipWith (\a b -> a*b)
        [ a | a<-[x,x-1..1] ]
        [ b | b <- [x,x-1..1], isPalindrome (a*b) ]
```

where it is pretty clear why `a` is not in scope for the last list comprehension. Intuitively, you should think of each `|` delimited part as being completely independent from the others. Any filtering operation is going to be bound to only *one* of these parts.

Comment: Wouldn't just replacing the second `|` with a `,` do the trick?

Comment: @Arnon No, then it would be a normal list comprehension rather than a parallel one, which will not be a `zipWith` but rather a `concatMap`.

Comment: That's at least an explanation. I had a look at the definition myself but since I am very new to Haskell (Started Yesterday) I didn't quite get it myself. Any tips on how to actually fix it though?

Comment: I just rethought the problem and realised I actually can't use parallel list comprehension at all...

Comment: Parallel list comprehensions entered the language just after I did, and I thought it was cool!  Then I proceeded to never use them.  There was a small phase of trying to extend list comprehensions with all sorts of features, but we seem to have grown out of it :)